# Trace a CGPath/UIBezierpath

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, uitouch

I would like the user to be able to trace a predefined CGPath/UIBezierpath with their finger and get a warning if they go outside of the lines (say the line thickness is e.g. 30px to make it easier).

How would I perform such a check based on the knowledge that the amount of events returned by the touch event methods vary depending on the finger's movement?

Answer (score 3):

Use `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` to create a path that outlines the stroked path.  Then use `CGPathContainsPoint` to test whether the touched point is inside that outline.

Comment: Thank. I don't think that's going to work though. If path A has a curve containing 20 points, and path B is a straight line containing the starting point and the ending point of A, then B's points will return a positive response even though these paths do not overlap.

Comment: That is a completely different problem that what you described in your original question.